# Variable "j" cannot be resolved as a variable - Two Dimensional Array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, compiler-errors

I am very new (5 days into) to programming. I have started with Java.
Now, I am stuck with this horrible error that I do not understand, nor know how to fix.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] TwoDim = new int [4][3];  // <-- 1st [rows]   , 2nd [columns]

    // TwoDim[2][1] = 10;  |\|\|\| this way, we can assign number 10 to row 2, column 1 , it's manual this way

    int temp = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++);
            TwoDim[i][j] = temp; // <<-- why isn't j resolved as a variable?!?!
            temp += 10;
        }
    }
}
```

I was creating a TwoDim array, trying to learn something from a youtube tutorial.
 the error in eclipse says ''j' cannot be resolved as a variable', even though I have created it in the 'for' loop. does this have something to do with the "j loop" being inside the "i loop"?

Comment: Lose that semicolon following the `j` for loop declaration; it counts as the body of the for loop!  Use braces for that inner for loop where appropriate.

Comment: You also need to wrap the code you want to execute in the for loop with curly brackets. Otherwise only the first line will after the for loop will be executed in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inner loop is empty due to the `;` after the `for`. `j` is only defined in the scope of that loop, which is empty. Open a block for the loop using `{` and `}`, and you should be OK:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) { // No ; here!
        TwoDim[i][j] = temp;
        temp += 10;
    }
}
```